# PHP: how do you get the method called from the constructor?

Tags: php, class, methods

PHP has get_called_class(); which will return the name of the class called. Is there a function to return the name of the method called? For example, I have a parent class:

```
class Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo get_called_class(); // echos "Child"
        // how do I echo "myMethod"
    }
}
```

Then I have a child parent:

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

If I call:

```
new Parent();
```

How do I get the name of the method called from the __construct - in this case "myMethod"? If I use `__FUNCTION__` it returns `Parent::__construct`.

EDIT: I'm trying to get the called class and method to be passed, automatically, to a view function. So in my controller action I can have:

```
$this->render();
```

instead of:

```
$this->render('account/new');
```

And my __construct will automatically have set

```
$controller = "account"; // from get_called_class();
$action = "new"; // gotten how?!
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Why do you need this? It suggests a design smell

Comment: when you create an object, __construct is called ...

Comment: Your code doesn't actually *call* `myMethod`...

Comment: If your parent constructor needs to call a particular method in children, define an interface for the child classes to implement... and use late static binding

Comment: I get the feeling you're going about trying to resolve this the wrong way, but the idea is valid. What I would do instead is have the view query something like the request so that it can try to determine a template. Your request object should have a controller and a method it wants to call, so your view object should look at the request as well to gather it's own information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple function to get a string in form "filename: [class->][function(): ]"

```
<?php
function get_caller_info() {
    $c = '';
    $file = '';
    $func = '';
    $class = '';
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    if (isset($trace[2])) {
        $file = $trace[1]['file'];
        $func = $trace[2]['function'];
        if ((substr($func, 0, 7) == 'include') || (substr($func, 0, 7) == 'require')) {
            $func = '';
        }
    } else if (isset($trace[1])) {
        $file = $trace[1]['file'];
        $func = '';
    }
    if (isset($trace[3]['class'])) {
        $class = $trace[3]['class'];
        $func = $trace[3]['function'];
        $file = $trace[2]['file'];
    } else if (isset($trace[2]['class'])) {
        $class = $trace[2]['class'];
        $func = $trace[2]['function'];
        $file = $trace[1]['file'];
    }
    if ($file != '') $file = basename($file);
    $c = $file . ": ";
    $c .= ($class != '') ? ":" . $class . "->" : "";
    $c .= ($func != '') ? $func . "(): " : "";
    return($c);
}
?>
```

Usage like:

```
<?php
function debug($str) {
    echo get_caller_info() . $str . "<br>\n";
}
?>
```

taken from [PHP Manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) which is MY best friend.

Comment: I was hoping to not use debug_backtrace, but it seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `__METHOD__`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Otherwise as others mentioned it should return __construct.

Comment: Right, I want it to return "myMethod" not "__construct".

Comment: In this case I think this function can be more useful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Answer (score 0):

As DCoder wrote, You don't call at all myMethod().
You construct Parent class object, not Child class object, so it's impossible to get in any way any function name or in general anything from Yout child class.